# StreamBuilder with KeepAlive performance issues ? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

I have a question what is if you have the same Stream in multiple Pages (StreamBuilder in every Page) with AutomaticKeepStateAliveClientMixin. Does this lead to performance issues for example if 6 Pages are open with lists with 150 items and the stream gets triggered. Because all 6 Pages rebuild or does flutter optimize it's performance on its own or is there a workaround.